# Sending a whole svn revision through ftp

Tags: svn, ftp, revision

My host does not handle SVN.

What I want is to be able to send through ftp a whole svn revision so I am sure I won't forget to upload a file.

Do you guys know any tool that would help me to do that?

Answer (score 8):

**The simple answer**

1. Do an SVN export on your local machine
2. Zip it
3. ftp to server
4. extract

Can then use ftp software like filezilla to upload / replace new files.  Can save time because it will prompt to only update files that have changed.

**The fancy answer**

1. Mount your ftp share on your machine as a local resource which is easy on linux / mac (fuse,ftpfs,sshfs), but requires [third party software on windows](http://www.google.ca/search?q=mount+windows+ftp).
2. Once you're mounted browse to it and use your local svn client to do a checkout onto the remote server.  Can be a bit flaky if connection is bad but I've done it before.
3. As long as it remains mounted you can treat it just like it was on your local machine
4. On windows you may want to enable TortoiseSVN to show Icon Labels on remote file systems

**The ideal scenario**

1. Find a host with ssh access and svn client
2. Either use [ssh port forwarding](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/11/06/ssh-port-forwarding/) to tunnel a connection to your svn server, or expose your svn server to the internet. (use [putty](http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html) on windows)
3. Then just do checkout on host and do updates to keep in sync.

**Note**

If SFTP is available you should use that because ftp isn't secure

Comment: Mounting a normal FTP share on Windows does *not* require third party software. Mounting a SFTP share does though.

Comment: There is another alternative, that is a command line utility called `lftp`. It doesn't have SVN access, but it can mirror an entire directory structure to a remote server, and it is entirely scriptable. The utility was written for linux but has been ported to mac and windows.

Answer (score 0):

I used SmartFTP and upload the entire folder. It will compare the contents of the files automatically (if you choose) and only upload the newer files, saves time and bandwidth

Comment: Saves bandwidth? If you want it to compare the entire contents of all files, it at least needs to download the entire site to your local machine. (Or is it using some CRC files somewhere?) It should be stated that SmartFTP only works on Windows and is therefore not useful foor all Linux and Mac users.